# Problem in downloading audio transcription datasets

Tags: dataset, dvc

I have been trying to download some datasets but I am having issues. Its using dvc, I tried using dvc fetch command but it didn't work. The data link - https://dagshub.com/mert.bozkirr/CREMA-D

I tried dvc fetch command, it did create the folders but didn't download the data

Comment: Hey. Can reproduce the issue as well, created an issue on github https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/9733

Comment: The issue is being looked at more closely in https://github.com/iterative/dvc/issues/9733 , but a workaround for now is to

```
dvc remote default origin
```

which sets the default remote to `origin` and works around the bug.